# clSetKernelArg throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I'm working through the HelloWorld example in the OpenCl Programming Guide and I keep getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to run this function (clSetKernelArg). The look of my function is basically...

```
clSetKernelArg(mKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), mMemObject[0]);
```

In the debugger everything looks to be instantiated. There's nothing null inside of the parenthesis and I'm all out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you declare the mMemObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going trough an OpenCL Hello World example I am almost certain that you do not have

```
cl_mem * mMemObject[foo]
```

That would be the only thing that would make the mMemObject[0] declaration legal. EXC_BAD_ACCESS implies that you are dereferencing an invalid pointer, and this implies that your mMemObject is just cl_mem.

This works if you have declared mMemObject simply with cl_mem mMemObject:

```
clSetKernelArg(mKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &mMemObject);
```

Comment: Oops. I was wrong it was this. 

   clSetKernelArg(mKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), mMem);

mMem is just cl_mem mMem = clCreateBuffer...

Comment: You were right. I'm wrapping it up and I was sending it as a cl_mem, which is a pointer, but I should have been taking the address of the cl_mem pointer instead. Thanks for the idiot check. I was going crazy.